# How to read typescript constructor and Record<> sentence

Tags: typescript, nestjs

When I read following code, I stacked the following `constructor`

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/exceptions/http.exception.ts

I'd like to understand what the

① What is `string | Record<string, any>,` ? what is the mean of this ?

② What is `super();` in this context ?

③Basically why this `constructor` is needed?

```
  constructor(
    private readonly response: string | Record<string, any>,
    private readonly status: number,
  ) {
    super();
    this.initMessage();
  }
```

If someone has opinion, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

① [Record<Keys, Type>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) is an utility type (built-in type)

> Constructs a type with a set of properties Keys of type Type. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type to another type.

Example

```js
// an object where the keys are 'first' and 'second' and the value is a number
const test: Record<'first' | 'second', number> = {
  'first': 123,
  'second': 456
}
```

In your case `Record<string, any>` it would be an object with any string as a key and `any` value.

② [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) is the class that the current class extends' constructor and with `super.method()` you can call super class' methods

③ Why is it needed - It defines the two private properties, which could also be defined outside of the constructor. And why does it calls  `initMessage` - that depends on the implementation

Comment: Thanks I still have a question. ② `super()` means, when we call constructor , The `HttpException` 's constructor will be called ? not the `Error` ? ③  What is `that depends on the implementation` ? As I am beginner ,, if there is some additional explanation, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Heisenberg [here's a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)) about the constructors

Answer (score 0):

1. `string | Record<string, any>` is a type definition for the response variable; it means the type will be `string` or `Record<string, any>`; you can read more about union typed at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html
2. in a constructor, you call `super()` when the class is extending another class. It looks like you omitted this part in your code snippet.
3. constructor is needed to initialize the class in question with response and status and whatever the extended class inits too

Answer (score 0):

1.- It means that the variable can be of 2 types: string or Record<string, any>

2.- The super keyword can be used in expressions to reference base class properties and the base class constructor. Super calls consist of the keyword super followed by an argument list enclosed in parentheses. Super calls are only permitted in constructors of derived classes.

3.- from what can be seen in the code, the constructor is used to initialize the variables or necessary methods from the moment the class is built